# Maven generation of javadoc fails while creating site

Tags: java, gwt, maven-2

I have a problem releasing my gwt project with maven (version 2.2.1).

The generation of the release files (war, sources, javadoc) works perfect. All files are generated and uploaded on my release repository.

Trouble starts during site generation. The generation of the javadoc fails while creating the site (mvn site:site). It worked perfectly some seconds earlier when running mvn javadoc:javadoc.

I am using same parent pom and therefore same basic configuration successfully in other projects, which don't include gwt.

For me it seems releated to using source-dependencies of hibernate validator, which I need for the gwt-plugin.

The error message is

> package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist

but org hibernate.validater is declared as a dependeny.

I have it 2 times in POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
....
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
....
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-site</id>
        <phase>site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>site</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <locales>de</locales>
          <outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</outputEncoding>
          <outputDirectory>F:\j2ee\projekte\...\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <linksource>true</linksource>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                <excludePackageNames>jsp.*</excludePackageNames>
              </configuration>
            </reportPlugin>
 .....
```

**Additional Info**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:67)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:29)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:441)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:386)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:424)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.processType(ClassTree.java:162)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.buildTree(ClassTree.java:114)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.<init>(ClassTree.java:73)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:104)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

I tried to change the order of the source- and binary-dependency, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would be nice to have the error with which the execution of site:site goal fails.. you can try to run mvn in debug mode to got some more info...

Comment: Can you explain why you have a dependency to a source part `<classifier>sources</classifier>` and a scope of *provided* which looks really wrong.

Comment: @hovanessyan I added the Stacktrace above. But I really think the root cause are the messages like package xyz does not exist.

Comment: @khmarbaise The source-dependency ist for the gwt compiler plugin. The gwt-compiler needs source code to produce javascript for the client side. For the own-written source the packages are mentioned in gwt module configuration (xxx.gwt.xml). Without the source-dependency the gwt-compiler plugin fails. The binary dependency is to compile server side calls to the hibernate validator.